# How to detect FB.init() is ready in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm using Unity3d and Facebook SDK!

when I click button login I want to call FB.Init() and then I call FBLogin (), so how can I detec FB.Init() is ready?

In document, I see FB.Init() in Awake() function, but I want if I click button, FB.Init() called!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function such as:

```
public void MyFBfunction(){

 //write FB.Init() code in here

}
```

And then call MyFBfunction() in the event of a button click.